# ClickOnce con Microsoft Edge Chromium pierde los parámetros pasados por URL

Tags: clickonce, edge

En una aplicación web tengo un botón que se utiliza para abrir una aplicación de escritorio WPF a la que se le pasa un parámetro, todo ello en .NET.

Todo esto funciona de forma correcta si la aplicación web se abre con Internet Explorer.

El problema viene cuando la aplicación web se abre con Microsoft Edge Chromium, que al llegar a la aplicación de escritorio ha perdido el parámetro. Leyendo por internet he visto que Edge Chromium no tiene soporte nativo para click once, pero he conseguido que se abra la aplicación, pero no que le llegue el parámetro.

Si alguien supiera si hay posibilidad de hacerlo y cómo se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saludos desde Uruguay.

El la ultima actualización de Edge Chromium se desactiva por defecto el soporte de clickonce... pero lo puedes volver a activar:

En la barra de direcciones pones:  edge://flags

Esto te abre una página de configuración donde encontrarás una llamada "ClickOnce Support"... la activas... reiniciar el navegador y listo.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Saludos